# Need help writing an SQL join query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table called "customer_requests":

```
[CustomerRequestID] 
[Title] 
[Description] 
[RFQDate] 
[Q2CDate] 
[QuantityRequested] 
[GST] 
[NetCost] 
[Markup] 
[NetSellPrice] 
[GrossSellPrice] 
[fkCustomerID] 
[Status]
```

And a table called "job":

```
[JobID] 
[JobTitle] 
[Description] 
[fkCustomerRequestID] 
[fkSupplierID] 
[fkSupplierQuoteID] 
[Quantity] 
[Cost] 
[Status] 
[ETA] 
[LoggedBy] 
[DeliveryAddress] 
[ParentJobID]
```

I want to write a select query that selects ALL entries from both tables, and displays them in the following table:

```
[QuoteNumber] (refers to CustomerRequestID in customer_requests, and fkCustomerRequestID in job)

[JobNumber] (refers to JobID in job, and is blank if the entry is from customer_requests)

[CustomerName] (selected using fkCustomerID in customer_requests, selected using fkCustomerRequestID->fkCustomerID in job)

[SupplierName] (selected using fkSupplierID in job, blank if entry is from customer_requests)

[JobTitle] (refers to title in customer_requests, and JobTitle in job)

[Quantity] (refers to QuantityRequested in customer_requests, and Quantity in Job)

[Cost]  (refers to GrossSellPrice in customer_requests and Cost in Job)

[ETA] (refers to ETA in Job, and blank if the entry is from customer_requests)

[Status] (refers to Status in customer_requests, and Status in Job)
```

How would I join these two together to make this table?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Something to the effect of this:

$query = "SELECT * FROM `job`";
$jobResult = mysql_query($query);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `customer_requests`";
$quoteResult = mysql_query($query);

<table>
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it fails to demonstrate a minimum understanding of the problem being solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the tables supplier and customer also:

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLENAME
SELECT j.fkCustomerRequestID,
    j.JobID,
    c.CustomerName,
    s.supplierName,
    j.JobTitle,
    j.Quantity,
    j.Cost,
    j.ETA,
    j.STATUS
FROM Jobs j
INNER JOIN supplier s ON j.fkSupplierID = s.SupplierID
INNER JOIN customer c ON j.fkCustomerRequestID = c.customerID
```

EDIT:

If you want all the information from both tables, you can do the query above and then UINON ALL with the following query:

```
SELECT cr.fkCustomerRequestID,
    "",
    c.CustomerName,
    "",
    cr.title,
    cr.QuantityRequested,
    cr.GrossSellPrice,
    "",
    cr.STATUS
FROM Jobs customer_requests
INNER JOIN customer c ON cr.fkCustomerID = c.customerID
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.  What I need it to do is select ALL entries from BOTH customer_requests AND job , basically a union.  So the new table will be made up of both customer requests and jobs.

Comment: @BlakeSiviour. I am editing my answer. See if it is closer. If it still isn't what you wanted, consider creating an [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with the tables and some example information